# Looking for an end user report designer control for WPF

Tags: wpf

I am looking for an end user report designer control for WPF. Syncfusion and Stimulsoft have report designer control for WPF. I didn’t get any other report designer control. Does anyone use any end user report designer control for WPF? It would be great helpful if you share your idea for using report designer control.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the WinForms Reporting Services control. We use it, it's fine. There's no WPF version yet. The WinForms looks nice and does what you want.

```
xmlns:viewer="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;assembly=Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms" 

<WindowsFormsHost HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <viewer:ReportViewer x:Name="viewerInstance" BorderStyle="None" />
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

Comment: By the way you can use native WPF viewer for SSRS: http://www.perpetuumsoft.com/WPF-Viewer-for-Reporting-Services.aspx together with this designer.

Comment: I think he is looking for report designer,not viewer. There are third party designers available. But they are not free.